# PHP form validation handling with Post/Redirect/Get

Tags: php, forms, validation, session

So I'm working on my website and I have a few forms. I created myself a little system to send/validate and add to the database if there aren't any errors. In my system I also use session variables to handle all the errors in the form since nothing is saved withe the Post/Redirect/Get technique.

The session variables are used to store the data sent so in case of an error you can repopulate the form and store some info on what is wrong with the form.

Putting together all these steps takes a lot of time, time that could be spent doing other stuff on my website.

I am hoping that someone has a solution that would be a lot easier to get up and working. Do any of you use session variables and do this or do you have another solution ?

I also use the jQuery validation plugin to validate it before submitting the form, but it is not really useful since my php form handling does everything it does.

Comment: Do any of you use session variables and do this or do you have an other solution ??

Comment: In order to get an answer, the question has to be specific enough for an answer to actually exist...

Comment: Does anyone have a better solution to my problem to propose ?

Comment: Simply put, your question boils down to "I don't want to spend time writing this code, gimme something shorter". Unfortunately, that is the shortest method I can think of, and it takes at most 10 lines per page of your form.

Comment: perhaps consider sticky forms: http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=412368&seqNum=3

Comment: "do you have an other solution ??" -> if you want to save time spent on reinventing the wheel you could have a look at some MVC framework (like Symfony2) but don't expect to have a good grip on it within only a few hours or even days.

Comment: @Blaine I'm going to look into that. Thanks

Comment: @mdo once my website is done, I'm going to learn how to use a framework either Symphony or YII and redo all my website. I'm doing it this way to get to learn php along the way.

Answer (score 2):

> In my system I also use session variables to handle all the errors in the form since nothing is saved withe the Post/Redirect/Get technique.

Just don't redirect when there are errors, but only redirect on successful and valid form  submit.

Comment: This is maybe what I'm going to try, but wouldn't that mean that if you reload the page that resend popup box will reappear ?

Comment: @JorisBlanc Yup it would display the popup which is fine imho because you are still trying to send the data.

Comment: Okay, I will still give it a try. Thanks

Comment: @PeeHaa If you don't redirect even when there is error, users will click a link, press Back on browser and pum... "The document expired". I think "Always redirect after POST" but I have no idead where to store the error message and form values. Session is not a good idea.